# How do I detect collisions in the python turtle module?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to find a way to check if two turtles (p1 and pipe1) are colliding. (note - I am new to Python programming and computer science in general)

I tried distance checking, and I was expecting it to run the function I wrote. Instead the program just ignored my code and nothing changed.

btw here is the code I wrote:

```
import turtle,time,random, math

#setup
wn = turtle.Screen()
p1 = turtle.Turtle()
pipe1 = turtle.Turtle()
pipe2 = turtle.Turtle()
pipe3 = turtle.Turtle()
pipe4 = turtle.Turtle()
msg = turtle.Turtle()
BG = turtle.Turtle()
BG2 = turtle.Turtle()
is_not_jump = True
Lose = False
p1.penup()
p1.goto(0,-50)
p1.speed(-1)
pipe1.speed(-1)
pipe2.speed(-1)
pipe3.speed(-1)
pipe4.speed(-1)
msg.speed(-1)
BG.speed(-1)
BG2.speed(-1)
wn.addshape("Sprites//P1.gif")
wn.addshape("Sprites//P1R.gif")
wn.addshape("Sprites//P1L.gif")
wn.addshape("Sprites//P1D.gif")
wn.addshape("Sprites//pipe.gif")
wn.addshape("Sprites//Pipe1.gif")
wn.addshape("Sprites//Pipe2.gif")
wn.addshape("Sprites//Pipe3.gif")
wn.addshape("Sprites//Pipe4.gif")
wn.addshape("Sprites//Back.gif")
wn.addshape("Sprites//Coin.gif")
BG.shape("Sprites//Back.gif")
BG2.shape("Sprites//Back.gif")
p1.shape("Sprites//P1.gif")
pipe1.shape("Sprites//Pipe1.gif")
pipe2.shape("Sprites//Pipe2.gif")
pipe3.shape("Sprites//Pipe3.gif")
pipe4.shape("Sprites//Pipe4.gif")
BG.goto(0,0)
BG.penup()
BG2.goto(0,700)
BG2.penup()
pipe1.penup()
pipe1.goto(87.5,350)
pipe2.penup()
pipe2.goto(-87.5,550)
pipe3.penup()
pipe3.goto(87.5,700)
pipe4.penup()
pipe4.goto(-87.5,850)
msg.hideturtle()
msg.penup()
msg.goto(0,50)
msg.write("Press Space to start!", align="Center", font=
          ("Comic Sans MS", 14, "bold"))
wn.setup(350,700)
p1.speed(0)
p1.goto(0,-50)
BG.goto(0,0)


#Controls
#def is_touch_y_up():
#    if p1.ycor()+28 <= pipe1.ycor-14:
#        return True
#    else:
#        return False

def p1_left():
        p1.shape("Sprites//P1L.gif")
        msg.clear()
        x = p1.xcor()-15
        p1.goto(x,p1.ycor())
def p1_right():
        p1.shape("Sprites//P1R.gif")
        msg.clear()
        x = p1.xcor()+15
        p1.goto(x,p1.ycor())
def fall():
    BG.setheading(270)
    BG2.setheading(270)
    pipe1.setheading(270)
    pipe2.setheading(270)
    pipe3.setheading(270)
    pipe4.setheading(270)
    while True:
        BG.forward(1)
        BG2.forward(1)
        pipe1.forward(2.5)
        pipe2.forward(2.5)
        pipe3.forward(2.5)
        pipe4.forward(2.5)
        if pipe1.ycor() <= -350:
            pipe1.goto(87.5,350)
        if pipe2.ycor() <= -350:
            pipe2.goto(-87.5,350)
        if pipe3.ycor() <= -350:
            pipe3.goto(87.5,350)
        if pipe4.ycor() <= -350:
            pipe4.goto(-87.5,350)
        if BG.ycor() <= -700:
            BG.goto(0,700)
        if BG2.ycor() <= -700:
            BG2.goto(0,700)
        if p1.ycor() <= -350:
            p1.goto(p1.xcor(),325)
        if p1.ycor() >= 350:
            p1.goto(p1.xcor(),-325)
        if is_not_jump:
            p1.setheading(270)
            p1.forward(5)
        if is_touch_y_up:
            lose()


def lose():
  while True:
    #pipe1.forward(0.01)
    #pipe2.forward(0.01)
    #pipe3.forward(0.01)
    #pipe4.forward(0.01)
    #pipe1.forward(-0.01)
    #pipe2.forward(-0.01)
    #pipe3.forward(-0.01)
    #pipe4.forward(-0.01)
    #BG.forward(0.01)
    #BG.forward(-0.01)
    #BG2.forward(0.01)
    #BG2 .forward(-0.01)
    is_not_jump == False
    wn.onkey(None,"Left")
    wn.onkey(None,"Right")
    wn.onkey(None, "space")
    p1.shape("Sprites//P1D.gif")
    msg.write("You lose...\nReopen this game to play again", align="Center", font=
          ("Comic Sans MS", 14, "bold"))

def jump():
    p1.shape("Sprites//P1.gif")
    msg.clear()
    is_not_jump = False
    p1.setheading(90)
    p1.forward(75)
    is_not_jump = True
    setup_keys()
    fall()


def setup_keys():   
        wn.onkey(lose,"r")
        wn.onkey(p1_left,"Left")
        wn.onkey(p1_right,"Right")


wn.onkey(jump, "space")
wn.listen()





turtle.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following function to check if two turtles have collided on the screen:

```
def collision_check(a, b):
    return abs(a.xcor() - b.xcor()) < 8 and abs(a.ycor() - b.ycor()) < 8
```

Here, `a` and `b` are parameters that require the two turtles you have.

In the function, `8` represents a collision radius based on the turtle size. You can adjust it to your liking.

You can use the function like:

```
if collision_check(turtle1, turtle2):
    print("Collision has taken place.")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, when I tried loading the game it automatically printed (or in my case run another function) at the start. I am not sure if it's a problem with the code itself or the fact that I put it in a while True loop

Answer (score 2):

Turtles have a built-in `distance()` method you can use for collision detection:

```
if p1.distance(pipe1) < 10
```

Where 10 represents the collision radius as @Dinux describes (+1)

Below is my (scaled back) rework of your code arranged the way I'd expect it to be structured:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

MESSAGE_FONT = ("Comic Sans MS", 14, 'bold')

# Controls

def is_touch_y_up():
    return p1.distance(pipe1) < 10

def p1_left():
    msg.clear()
    p1.setx(p1.xcor() - 15)

def p1_right():
    msg.clear()
    p1.setx(p1.xcor() + 15)

def fall():
    pipe1.setheading(270)
    pipe1.forward(2.5)

    if pipe1.ycor() <= -350:
        pipe1.goto(87.5, 350)

    if p1.ycor() <= -350:
        p1.sety(325)
    elif p1.ycor() >= 350:
        p1.sety(-325)

    if is_not_jump:
        p1.setheading(270)
        p1.forward(5)

    if is_touch_y_up():
        screen.ontimer(lose)
    else:
        screen.ontimer(fall)

def lose():
    global is_not_jump

    is_not_jump = False

    screen.onkey(None, 'r')
    screen.onkey(None, 'Left')
    screen.onkey(None, 'Right')
    screen.onkey(None, 'space')

    msg.clear()
    msg.write("You lose...\nReopen this game to play again", align='center', font=MESSAGE_FONT)

is_not_jump = True

def jump():
    global is_not_jump

    msg.clear()
    is_not_jump = False
    p1.setheading(90)
    p1.forward(75)
    is_not_jump = True

# setup
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(350, 700)

p1 = Turtle()
p1.shape('turtle')
p1.speed('fastest')
p1.penup()
p1.sety(-50)

pipe1 = Turtle()
pipe1.shape('square')
pipe1.speed('fastest')
pipe1.penup()
pipe1.goto(87.5, 350)

msg = Turtle()
msg.speed('fastest')
msg.hideturtle()
msg.penup()
msg.sety(50)
msg.write("Press Space to start!", align='center', font=MESSAGE_FONT)

screen.onkey(lose, 'r')
screen.onkey(p1_left, 'Left')
screen.onkey(p1_right, 'Right')
screen.onkey(jump, 'space')
screen.listen()

fall()

screen.mainloop()
```

See if my changes make sense to you.

Comment: The 2 turtles have different sizes so distance checking wouldn't work